# Is there a way to use Vuetify directly without a CDN?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use Vuetify on a Vue project. On other occasions I've downloaded directly the source code for different css frameworks so that I have more control and flexibility than just using a cdn. I'm trying to do the same for Vuetify, and having difficulty finding an entry point.

I was able to find the source code using unpkg here:

https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.18/dist/vuetify.js

https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.18/dist/vuetify.css

And make a direct file for my project, hook it up to the intended file, but it isn't rendering any of the expected styles. I already found one mapping dependency it needed that I hadn't been satisfying earlier, and I'm wondering if there are others that it isn't meeting either. I've tried going through the official documentation and the closest thing I've found is the a-la-carte option, but it isn't exactly what I was looking for.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte

I'm curious if anyone has experience doing this before - using the source code verisons of js and css files in a project instead of the CDN or yarn or npm installations, which it seems to want to point you toward heavily.

Comment: Can you post how you're using it?

Comment: _"but it isn't rendering any of the expected styles"_ and what are these styles? Are you sure they were meant to come from the core vuetify library and not some other? _"I already found one mapping dependency it needed that I hadn't been satisfying earlier"_ Could that be due to you using some other library's stuff and mistakenly thinking it  was provided by vuetify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The production build is the zip file available here - https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v1.0.18